# Is Patema Inverted available in English Dub?

Tags: patema-inverted

I know many people say that subbed anime is better than dubbed, but is *Patema Inverted* available in English dub? If so, where can I watch it?

Comment: Welcome to Anime.SE! Please be aware that we do not condone piracy here, so any answers will only point to official sources like Crunchyroll.

Answer (score 1):

The [ANN](https://www.animenewsnetwork.com/encyclopedia/anime.php?id=13906) site of the movie has a list of streaming platforms where it is supposed to be available.
I found it on [Amazon Prime Video](https://www.amazon.com/gp/video/detail/B00OPJSUZY/ref=atv_dp_share_cu_r) where it is indicated that the audio is in English.

Comment: @BCLC Comments are not meant to discuss edit rejections. You can discuss it on [meta] instead